# Why Calling An RPC Function With An Integer Parameter Gives Error? -Photon Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rpc, photon

I am Using Photon 2 And I Have Public Rpc Function In One Of My Script, The Function Has An Integer Parameter, This Is How My Function Exactly Looks Like.

```
    [PunRPC]
    public void TakeDamage(int amount)
    { 
        playerHealth -= amount;
        if (playerHealth <= 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Player Died");        
        }
    }
```

We In Above Code The TakeDamage Function Takes An Integer Called amount. So When I am Calling This Function From Other Scripts, And When The Other scripts Actually Call The Function It Gives A Warning.

### How I am Calling The Fucntion

```
PV.RPC("currentTarget.TakeDamage",  RpcTarget.AllBuffered, damage);
```

The PV is a public PhotonView.

### The Warning

```
RPC method 'currentTarget.TakeDamage(Int32)' not found on object with PhotonView 1003. Implement as non-static. Apply [PunRPC]. Components on children are not found.
```

Comment: Try calling the RPC without „currentTarget“ i.e.  `PV.RPC("TakeDamage", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, damage);`

Comment: Just as an aside I would recommend using `nameof` instead of the string name of the method. This way if you rename the method name later on it automatically updates and it stops any accidental spelling mistakes.

Comment: @JeanLuc Yes, But That Function Is Actually Not A Global Function, I Mean I Call That Function On Shooting Script(Raycast)  I Only Want To Call That Function  On Object Which Which The Raycast Hits, I Won't Mean To Give Damage To All Online Players In Room.

Comment: @JeanLuc Thanks After all, I Used Your Suggestion And Played Around With Script I Finally Got What I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give function name `("TakeDamage")` instead of `"currentTarget.TakeDamage"` in RPC function.